# Interactive Report - aggregate sum of multiple columns from one table multiply by values from another Table

Tags: aggregate, oracle-apex

I have a challenge in Oracle Apex - I would to sum multiple columns to give 3 extra rows namely points, Score, %score. There are more columns but I'm only choosing a few for now. 
Below is an example structure of my data:

```
Town | Sector  |  Outside| Inside |Available|Price
Roy-----Formal----0----------0----------1------0
Kobus --Formal----0 ---------0--------- 1------0
Wika ---Formal----0----------0--------- 1------0
Mevo----Formal----1----------1----------1------0
Hoch----Formal----1----------1----------1------1            
Points------------2----------2----------5------1
Score------------10---------10---------10------10
%score-----------20---------20---------50------10
```

Each column has a constant weighting (which serves as a factor and it can change depending on the areas). In this case, the weighting for the areas are in the first row of the sector Formal:

```
Sector |Outside| Inside |Available|Price
Formal----1----------1 ----------1-----1
Informal--1----------0 ----------2-----1
```

I tried using the aggregate sum function in apex but it wont work because I need the factor in the other table. This is where my challenge began.

To compute the rows below the report
 
**points** = sum per column * weighting factor per column
**Score** = sum of no of shops visited (in this case its 5) * weighting factor per column
**% score** = points/Score * 100

The report should display as described above. With the new computed rows below.
I kindly ask anyone to assist me with this challenge as I have tried searching for solutions but haven't come across any.

Thanks a lot for your support in advance!!

Comment: Just to be clear: does it have to be an interactive report? Is your set of data so large that you want to use pagination? Do these calculated totals have to reflect currently visible values in that case or totals for all rows? Would a classic report be acceptable as a solution?

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your prompt response. It doesnt have to be an interactive report as long as the report will display as discribed above. The data is large and there are 31 columns and the data will grow with each insert. The calculated values should show as rows for all the columns. Any report is prefered as long as i get the desired output. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi Tom, No need to look into this anymore, i found the solution.